# IBOutlet Connections and Inheritance

Tags: ios, inheritance, interface-builder, iboutlet

I'm having two issues with a interstitial class hierarchy I'm writing at the moment.

There's a base class for my interstitials:

- Base class:     JSBaseCustomizeableIntersitialView
- Child class[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS3P1.png): JSInviteFriendsCustomizableIntersititialView
- Child class[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS3P1.png): JSBadgeCustomizableIntersititialView

The base class holds the IBOutlets for common UI for every interstitial I'm going to be developing:  title, description, a "flavor" image, and ok/cancel button.

Each subclass has its own View in a xib file, which I'm trying to connect to the outlets declared on the base class.

Any idea how to do this?  Here's a graphical example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

(open image in full screen mode [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS3P1.png))

Comment: Set the class in identity inspector of Interface Builder to that of the subclass you want that View to be associated with, then hook up the outlets via the connections inspector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within `Interface Builder`, select the `Identity Inspector` from the `Utilities` pane. In the `Custom Class` section, fill out your required subclass there.

Then select the `Connections Inspector` and hook-up your required outlets.

Repeat this for each UIView you have.

[image]